# If Psalm 27 was said during Ma'ariv and Shachrit, should it be said during Mincha, also?

Tags: tefilla, minhag, nusach-ashkenaz, nusach-sefard

I see that Psalm 27 is said twice daily. But the tefillot during which it is said differ:

- Nusach Ashkenaz says Psalm 27 during *Ma'ariv* while Nusach Sefard does not.
- Both Nusach Ashkenaz and Sefard say it during Shacharit.
- Nusach Sefard says it during Mincha while Nusach Ashkenaz does not.

Let's say someone who usually davens Nusach Ashkenaz entered a Nusach Sefard shul for Mincha. He has already fulfilled his twice daily recitation. Does he need to say it a third time during Mincha just because he is now in a Nusach Sefard shul?

Comment: Fwiw ( not much) I think nusach sfard has the right minhag on this one so no harm done. A Rosh Yeshiva I know told a talmid to repeat.

Comment: Why should he not repeat it? There is no problem saying a Kapitel Tehilim.

Comment: @user6591 See if you can find out why this is the "right" minhag.

Comment: DanF the source to say it is in the achronim in siman 581. M.B. tacks it on the ramma who mentions blowing the shofar in the morning and evening. Evening in the ramma means either after mincha according to chayei adam or after maariv as long as they prayed maariv early, during daylight hours. That's how igros moshe explains the magen avraham there. So the newer minhag of lidovid is going to be the same as shofar i.e. during the day.

Comment: @user6591 That's assuming the new minhag is based on something. If people develop a minhag to say a chapter of tehillim at a certain time, that's their minhag. It doesn't really matter what other minhagim happen t exist or why. A minhag to recite a chapter of Nechemiah at 1pm is just as real.

Comment: @double that is a good point. I was basing the association off the M.B. Lumping them together which is probably wrong to do. Where else should he write it? It seems the source for this m.b. is the mateh ephraim who definitely does not base this Minhag off the shofar, so good call on that. However M.E. Does say it should be said after mincha. The commentary katzeh limata brings a variant minhag who say it after maariv.

Comment: DanF the psak from the rosh yeshiva was even more interesting. The boy in yeshiva davened nusach sfard but the yeshiva davened ashkenaz. The rosh yeshiva told him to say it by both. ( which i assume the rosh yeshiva did himself as he also davens sfard) By mincha to keep his own minhag and by maariv so as not to be poresh from the tzibur!

Comment: **Nusach Ashkenaz says Psalm 27** - well, some do. The original Nusach Ashkenaz, still followed by many Yekkes did not adopt this new custom (of dubious origin) at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this follows the general rule mentioned in the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch in 17:10 -  סימן יז - הלכות קריאת שמע - that if one is **with a congregation one should say what they are saying - even if one has already prayed** - so as not to separate oneself from the congregation.

> **סעיף י'**:
>   קָרָא קְרִיאַת שְׁמַע וְנִכְנַס לְבֵית הַכְּנֶסֶת, וּמָצָא צִבּוּר שֶׁקּוֹרִין קְרִיאַת שְׁמַע, צָרִיךְ לִקְרֹת עִמָּהֶם כָּל קְרִיאַת שְׁמַע, שֶׁלֹּא יֵרָאֶה כְּאִלּוּ אֵינוֹ רוֹצֶה לְקַבֵּל עֹל מַלְכוּת שָׁמַיִם עִם חֲבֵרָיו, וִיקַבֵּל שָׂכָר כְּקוֹרֵא בַּתּוֹרָה, וְהוּא הַדִּין אִם הוּא בְּבֵית הַכְּנֶסֶת, וְאוֹמֵר דִּבְרֵי תַּחֲנוּנִים, אוֹ פְּסוּקִים בְּמָקוֹם שֶׁרַשַּׁאי לְהַפְסִיק (וְאִם עוֹמֵד בְּמָקוֹם שֶׁאֵינוֹ רַשַּׁאי נִתְבָּאֵר לְעֵיל) וְאִם הוּא עֲדַיִן לֹא קָרָא קְרִיאַת שְׁמַע, קוֹרֵא גַּם כֵּן עִם הַצִבּוּר, אֲבָל צָרִיךְ שֶׁיִּתְכַּוֵּן שֶׁלֹּא לָצֵאת יְדֵי חוֹבָתוֹ, כְּדֵי שֶׁיִּקְרָא אַחַר כָּךְ עִם הַבְּרָכוֹת, **וְכֵן שְׁאָר דְּבָרִים שֶׁהַצִבּוּר אוֹמְרִים, כְּגוֹן תְּהִלָּה לְדָוִד, וְעָלֵינוּ, וְכַדּוֹמֶה וַאֲפִלּוּ פִּיּוּטִים אוֹמֵר עִמָּהֶם, וְאַל יִפְרֹשׁ אֶת עַצְמוֹ מִן הַצִּבּוּר**.‏

All the more so when one is praying with a congregation that is just saying a *Kapitel Tehillim,* there's no reason to stand there idly waiting for them to finish.

Comment: Stand idly, sure, but let's say you haven't said Korbanot yet that day and aren't going to bother to later (as if we're honest is often the case for most people). Wouldn't Parshat HaTamid be more important than a _third_ round of an already strictly unnecessary addition?

Comment: @DoubleAA - IDK. Don't see that being discussed anywhere.